# Conversion problem from Lambert93 to WGS84 - R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, wgs84

I am dealing with IGN shapefiles of french "communes" that are in Lambert93 projection.

`temp <- readOGR(dsn = chemin)
 temp@proj4string`

which gives

`CRS arguments:
 +proj=lcc +lat_1=44 +lat_2=49 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80
+units=m +no_defs`

I would like to focus on the attached dataset and to use the coordinates of some points :

`data.temp <- as.data.frame(temp@data)
  coordinates(data.temp) <- ~X_CHF_LIEU+Y_CHF_LIEU`

if we look at the coordinates :

`> coordinates(data.temp.centr)
      X_CHF_LIEU Y_CHF_LIEU
0           1743      68564
1           7919      63428
2           7747      63253
3           5284      64353
4           9895      68015
5           7931      63483`

But I would like to have this in the WGS84 projection system. In order to do so, I first assign the initial CRS to spatial data frame I extracted. And then re-project it.

`data.temp@proj4string <- temp@proj4string
  data.temp <- spTransform(data.temp, 
                                  CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +"))`

But unfortunately, it gives unrelevant coordinates :

`> coordinates(data.temp.centr)
      X_CHF_LIEU Y_CHF_LIEU
0      -1.375898  -5.554938
1      -1.335507  -5.584978
2      -1.336522  -5.586134
3      -1.352299  -5.580093
4      -1.324725  -5.555561
5      -1.335450  -5.584630`

but obviously, it is not in France anymore.. Any idea why I'm not ending with proper WGS84 coordinates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, if you read the metadata of your shapefiles, provided by the IGN on their website, you'll see that coordinates in the table are divided by 100 (not 1000 as written in previous version). So that you should do:

```
data.temp$long <- data.temp$X_CHF_LIEU * 100
data.temps$lat <- data.temp$Y_CHF_LIEU * 100
coordinates(data.temp) <- ~long+lat
```

Comment: I didn't know this, but looks about right. @user8324208 if you compare the Lambert coordinates in your example and the projected bounds of the [coordinate system](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2154/), you can notice that their orders of magnitutde are different.

Comment: Yes, in fact, I sorted the issue out by noticing that the coords were provided in hectometers and not in meters. So that, it should be multiplied by 100 and not 1000. But it is the idea. Thanks!